# Is there a way for a mock Function to return different values in subsequent calls?

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I want a similar behaviour as below. How can I do it in Ballerina?

```
 isolated function testFunc() returns string|error {
      // ...
      return str;
 }

    // mocking testFunc

    string val1 = testFunc(); // return value 1
    string val2 = testFunc(); // return value 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/mocking/#stub-with-multiple-values-to-return-sequentially-for-each-function-call functionality if you are using object mocking. But with function mocking, There is no support for multiple stubs. You can  reset the return value for a function call before each call. You can utilize the call option and implement the custom logic within that function as well.

**main.bal**

function to mock

```
public function intAdd(int a, int b) returns int {
    return (a + b);
}
```

**test.bal**

```
import ballerina/test;

@test:Mock {functionName: "intAdd"}
test:MockFunction intAddMockFn = new ();

@test:Config {}
function testReturn() {
    // Stub to return the specified value when the `intAdd` is invoked.
    test:when(intAddMockFn).thenReturn(20);
   
    // Stub to return the specified value when the `intAdd` is invoked with the specified arguments.
    test:when(intAddMockFn).withArguments(0, 0).thenReturn(-1);
}
```

As shown in above example you can mock a function differently based on the arguments.